# Update/Delete in Spring mvc with JdbcTemplate with mysql database?

Tags: mysql, spring, model-view-controller, jdbctemplate

I'm performing CRUD in Spring MVC on two tables.My two table employeedetail [master table] and login[child table] with employeeid as foreign key. When i'm running my Query

Query 1.

```
DELETE e.* ,l.* FROM  employeedetail e JOIN login l ON l.employeeid=e.employeeid WHERE l.employeeid=10;
```

Error:

> Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`springmvcmaven`.`login`, CONSTRAINT
>   `employee_login_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`employeeid`) REFERENCES
>   `employeedetail` (`employeeid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO
>   ACTION)

Query 2:

```
 DELETE e.* ,l.* FROM  employeedetail e JOIN login l ON l.employeeid=e.employeeid WHERE employeeid=10;
```

ERROR :

> Error Code: 1052. Column 'employeeid' in where clause is ambiguous

can any help me with this.

Comment: `WHERE employeeid=10;` must be `WHERE l.employeeid=10;` or `WHERE e.employeeid=10;`

Comment: I did both way but you can see error above of foreign key constraint

Comment: Delete all record from the child table before deleting the parent

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:-**

In the foreign key constraints, you can declare it as `ON DELETE CASCADE`. So that when the record in master table is deleted, all the records in the child table will be deleted automatically.

[Refer delete on cascade](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/)

**Solution 2:-**

Delete the child table records i.e. `login` table first

Delete the master table record i.e. `employeedetail` table

```
DELETE FROM  login l WHERE l.employeeid=10;
DELETE FROM  employeedetail e WHERE e.employeeid=10;
```

Comment: But the problem is i'm doing with Spring MVC and i'm deleting from JdbcTemplate.update(sql,obj); So here is the problem, how to manage two query in this ?

Comment: what sql query are you using in update method? Can you show that? Is that same as what you have mentioned in OP ? If you are using sql query using jdbc template update method, you can execute the update method twice with two different delete statements as I mentioned in my solution.

Comment: yeah it is same which i've mentioned above, can you please provide me example, i tried every possible solution but could find since morning       This my delete                                                                                    
       public int deleteData(int employeeid){
  String sql="DELETE e.*,l.* FROM employeedetail e INNER JOIN login l ON e.employeeid=l.employeeid WHERE l.employeeid=?";  
  return Template.update(sql,new Object[]{employeeid});
 }